# Nested Controllers in angularJS - no access second controller from third controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 div elements and 3 controllers.

The second controller has access to the first controller. but third one is not working.

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", [])

        .controller("countryController", function () {
            this.Name = "Turkey";
        })

        .controller("cityController", function () {
            this.Name = "Istanbul";
        })

        .controller("streetController", function () {
            this.Name = "Istiklal";
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="countryController as countryCtrl">
        {{countryCtrl.Name}}
        <div ng-controller="cityController as cityCtrl">
            {{countryCtrl.Name}} -  {{cityCtrl.Name}}
        </div>
        <div ng-controller="streetController as streetCtrl">
            {{countryCtrl.Name}}  - {{cityCtrl.Name}}  {{streetCtrl.Name}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$parent`....will help you.

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get `{{cityCtrl.Name}}` as it is a sibling of the third controller. Instead you can either use `$parent` or `$rootScope` to get the value.

Or nest it within the second contoller:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", [])

  .controller("countryController", function() {
    this.Name = "Turkey";
  })
  .controller("cityController", function() {
    this.Name = "Istanbul";
  })
  .controller("streetController", function() {
    this.Name = "Istiklal";
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="countryController as countryCtrl">
  {{countryCtrl.Name}}
  <div ng-controller="cityController as cityCtrl">
    {{countryCtrl.Name}} - {{cityCtrl.Name}}

    <div ng-controller="streetController as streetCtrl">
      {{countryCtrl.Name}} - {{cityCtrl.Name}} {{streetCtrl.Name}}
    </div>
  </div><!--cityCtrl closed-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it this way: 
`streetCtrl` is **not** a child of `cityCtrl`.

This is not the best way to share data between controllers, you should probably use a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).

Here is a [dummy Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/fu82re48/) showing how it works.